# JavaScript fetch function fails to get .txt file

Tags: leaflet, html

I'm creating a web page with a Leaflet map, and when clicking on a certain marker on the map, information about the location appears in a div beside it.

I can update this information directly in the js code this way:

```js
var cityMarker = L.marker([82.66787727945918, -153.585859355341]).addTo(map);
  cityMarker.bindPopup(`<h3>Phandalin</h3> 
  <p class="locDesc">Vila</p>
  `).on('click', () => {
      map.flyTo([82.66787727945918, -153.585859355341], 6);
      document.getElementById("mapInfo").innerHTML = "<h1>Nome da Cidade</h1> <p>Descrição da cidade.</p>";
  }).addTo(map);
```

So the div information updates to what is described.

But, as the description of the cities are very big and there are also many cities, I decided to make a .txt file for each city, with the necessary information, in order to make my code cleaner.

For example: a city1.txt file with the following text inside:
`<h1>Nome da Cidade</h1> <p>Descrição da cidade.</p>`

But when using the fetch function as follows:

```js
var cityMarker = L.marker([82.66787727945918, -153.585859355341]).addTo(map);
  cityMarker.bindPopup(`<h3>Cidade 1</h3> 
  <p class="locDesc">Vila</p>
  `).on('click', () => {
      map.flyTo([82.66787727945918, -153.585859355341], 6);
      fetch('./web/all_maps/dnd/forgotten_realms/continents/faerun/locations/cidade1.txt')
         .then(response => response.text())
         .then(data => {
          document.getElementById("mapInfo").innerHTML = data;
      })
  }).addTo(map);
```

there in the HTML page, instead of updating the Div with the information contained in the .txt, the following appears inside the div:

`Cannot GET /web/all_maps/dnd/forgotten_realms/continents/faerun/web/all_maps/dnd/forgotten_realms/continents/faerun/locations/city1.txt`

Could anyone tell what the problem is?

Comment: What errors are reported in the browser debugger network section and console?

Comment: Can you reach that URL in your browser?

Comment: @TomazicM "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" That error, apear in console.log.

Comment: @geocodezip yes, when a enter it in my browser shows the information in .txt

Comment: Is it publicly available on your webserver?

Comment: This not really a GIS question, but completely HTML/JS oriented one and such more suitable for StackOverflow site.